# JS dynamically load responsive images and find out when they are loaded

Tags: javascript, image, media-queries, responsive, preload

***Background:***

There is a website with many, many images.
However, the user only needs to receive the first 15 images immediately.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()
{
 function loaded_3()
 {
 document.getElementById("left").innerHTML += "<br><br><strong>ALL DONE :)</strong><br><br>";
 }

 function loaded_2()
 {
 document.getElementById("left").innerHTML += "<br><br><strong>OK - images 16-30 have also loaded successfully!</strong><br>NOW LOADING THE REMAINING 5 IMAGES!<br>";


 var last_divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-last-id]'));

  last_divs.forEach(function(element)
  {
  element.setAttribute('id', element.getAttribute('data-last-id'));
  document.getElementById("left").innerHTML += 'id="' + element.getAttribute('data-last-id') + '" was set successfully!<br>';
  });

 window.removeEventListener("load", loaded_2);
 window.addEventListener("load", loaded_3);
 }

 function loaded_1()
 {
 document.getElementById("left").innerHTML += "<strong>OK - images 1-15 have loaded successfully!</strong><br><br>";

 var divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-id]'));

  divs.forEach(function(element)
  {
  element.setAttribute('id', element.getAttribute('data-id'));
  document.getElementById("left").innerHTML += 'id="' + element.getAttribute('data-id') + '" was set successfully!<br>';
  });

 window.removeEventListener("load", loaded_1);
 window.addEventListener("load", loaded_2);
 }

 window.addEventListener("load", loaded_1);
});
```

```css
*
{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
border-style:none;
box-sizing:border-box;
}

html, body
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#left
{
position:absolute;
width:400px;

left:0px;
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
background-color:#ffcc00;
padding:20px;
}

#right
{
position:absolute;
left:400px;
top:0px;
right:0px;
bottom:0px;
background-color:#eeeeee;
padding:20px;
}


#one { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ffcc00/cc33ff); }
#two { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ff0000/000000); }
#three { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/00cc00/33cccc); }
#four { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/330033/ff33ff); }
#five { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ffcccc/0033ff); }
#six { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/bbcc11/dddd00); }
#seven { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/0033bb/222bbb); }
#eight { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/2211bb/00bb11); }
#nine { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ffcc00/22ccff); }
#ten { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ffcc00/33ccff); }
#eleven { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/f0cc00/333333); }
#twelve { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/f1c20b/c13bf2); }
#thirteen { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/f0cd00/cf33f0); }
#fourteen { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ff0b01/0001ff); }
#fifteen { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ffbb00/dd31ff); }
#sixteen { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ffd100/cc33ff); }
#seventeen { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ffec10/000000); }
#eighteen { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/fbccfd/ff33ff); }
#nineteen { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ccccff/cf33f0); }
#twenty { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/00ccee/cc33ff); }
#twentyone { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ddccee/dddd00); }
#twentytwo { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/bbee00/cc33ff); }
#twentythree { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/11c000/c13bf2); }
#twentyfour { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/44c200/00bb11); }
#twentyfive { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/22ca00/33cccc); }
#twentysix { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/bbcf00/cc33ff); }
#twentyseven { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ffbb00/00bb11); }
#twentyeight { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/eedd00/cc33ff); }
#twentynine { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/00ff00/33ccff); }
#thirty { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/220000/c13bf2); }

.testdiv
{
width:30px;
height:30px;
overflow:hidden;
margin:5px;

display:inline-block;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:30px;
color:#ffffff;
text-align:center;
line-height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="left"></div>

<div id="right">

<div class="testdiv" id="one">1</div>
<div class="testdiv" id="two">2</div>
<div class="testdiv" id="three">3</div>
<div class="testdiv" id="four">4</div>
<div class="testdiv" id="five">5</div>
<div class="testdiv" id="six">6</div>
<div class="testdiv" id="seven">7</div>
<div class="testdiv" id="eight">8</div>
<div class="testdiv" id="nine">9</div>
<div class="testdiv" id="ten">10</div>
<div class="testdiv" id="eleven">11</div>
<div class="testdiv" id="twelve">12</div>
<div class="testdiv" id="thirteen">13</div>
<div class="testdiv" id="fourteen">14</div>
<div class="testdiv" id="fifteen">15</div>

<div class="testdiv" data-id="sixteen">16</div>
<div class="testdiv" data-id="seventeen">17</div>
<div class="testdiv" data-id="eighteen">18</div>
<div class="testdiv" data-id="nineteen">19</div>
<div class="testdiv" data-id="twenty">20</div>
<div class="testdiv" data-id="twentyone">21</div>
<div class="testdiv" data-id="twentytwo">22</div>
<div class="testdiv" data-id="twentythree">23</div>
<div class="testdiv" data-id="twentyfour">24</div>
<div class="testdiv" data-id="twentyfive">25</div>

<div class="testdiv" data-last-id="twentysix">26</div>
<div class="testdiv" data-last-id="twentyseven">27</div>
<div class="testdiv" data-last-id="twentyeight">28</div>
<div class="testdiv" data-last-id="twentynine">29</div>
<div class="testdiv" data-last-id="thirty">30</div>

</div> <!-- right -->
```

The next 10 images should be loaded as soon as the first 15 images have loaded.
And the last 5 images should loaded after the first 15 and the next 10 images have finished loading.

Here is what I tried:
https://filebin.net/01s7w1grpybvkiis/fourth.html

My approach was to set an id="" only, and let CSS do the media queries.
Of course I could use JS to load the images (then I could easily find out which ones have loaded), but I need to take care of both, CSS-width *and* also pixel-ratio!!

So I cannot load specific images in JS,  because the background-image to be loaded will be a different one, depending on CSS-width and Pixel Ratio (not implemented in my test case, but you need to have this information!).

That's why I tried it with JS and CSS together (see example: https://filebin.net/01s7w1grpybvkiis/fourth.html)

I found a library for JS (named enquire.js) which says it could do media queries in pure JS but it failed to use media-queries for pixel-ratio so I am again trying it with CSS media queries.

How can I write a pure JavaScript solution for this? I prefer not to use jQuery at this stage.

Comment: Hi, can you please edit the relevant bits of your code here into the question? Questions here on Stack Overflow are expected to be functional even if any of the linked external sources go down.

Comment: Also can you clarify what you want to achieve - this `The next 10 images should be loaded as soon as the first 15 images have loaded` sounds like the default behaviour when just listing one image after another, no?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I had a look and the code is really extensive so I did not copy it in here. Ronny, try to create a [mcve] here using the `<>` button in the editor

Comment: @mplungjan  the code is already is short as possible :(  I just try to find the button where I can add source code.  However, I need to load the images externally as I guess I cannot upload them here.

Comment: You can use lorem pixel - ctrl-m loads the code editor when you edit your question

Comment: @Pekka the default behaviour should really load one image and then the next and so on.  However,  in real life images load parallel.  In my special case, I let it up to the browser to decide when to load what image (<img> for example has a higher priority to most browsers than background-images) - I personally only want, that the images 1-15 are loaded first of all.  THEN, once it's sure that the images 1-15 have loaded, the next set of images (16-25) should load.  And once it's certain that they also loaded, the last 5 images should load.  The order in which order they load does NOT care.

Comment: @mplungjan thank you for the tip with CTRL+M  !!  the post is updated with a test case.  Sorry that is the smallest test-case I can think of!

Answer (score 0):

So far this is what I did:

```js
console.clear();
        checkBackgroundLoad();
        var imgSrc = [];
        document.body.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
            var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
            //console.log(imgs);
            for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
                var src = imgs[i].getAttribute('src');
                if (imgSrc.indexOf(src) > -1) return;
                imgSrc.push(src);
                if (imgs[i].complete) continue;
                imgs[i].onload = function () { console.log("Loaded Image"); }
                imgs[i].onerror = function () { console.log("Fail to Load Image"); }
            }

            checkBackgroundLoad();

        }, false);

        function checkBackgroundLoad() {
            var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
            for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
                var id = all[i].getAttribute("id");
                var style = all[i].currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(all[i], false);
                //console.log(style);
                var bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1);
                LoadBackgroundImage(bi, id);
            }
        }

        var uniqueImg = [];
        var countLoad = 0;
        var completionCallback = undefined;

        function LoadBackgroundImage(bi, id) {
            if (bi.length < 1) return;
            if (countLoad < 1) return;
            bi = bi.replace(new RegExp('"', 'g'), '');
            //var imageName = bi.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "");
            if (uniqueImg.indexOf(bi) != -1) {
                //countLoad--;
                return;
            }
            uniqueImg.push(bi);
            console.log(id);
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
                console.log("Loaded Background Image");
                LogLoad(id);
                CompleteLoad();
            };
            img.onerror = function () {
                console.log("Fail to load Background Image");
                CompleteLoad();
            }
            img.src = bi;
        }

        function CompleteLoad() {
            countLoad--;
            //console.log(countLoad);
            if (countLoad > 0) return;
            if (countLoad == 0) {
                //uniqueImg = [];
                completionCallback();
                return;
            }
        }

        function LogLoad(id) {
            document.getElementById("left").innerHTML += 'id="' +
                id +
                '" Loaded <br>';
        }


        function firstBatch() {
            var divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[first-id]'));
            countLoad = divs.length;
            completionCallback = secondBatch;
            divs.forEach(function (element) {
                element.setAttribute('id', element.getAttribute('first-id'));
                document.getElementById("left").innerHTML += 'id="' +
                    element.getAttribute('first-id') +
                    '" start loading!<br>';
            });
        }

        var secondBatch = function () {
            var divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-id]'));
            countLoad = divs.length;
            completionCallback = thirdBatch;
            divs.forEach(function (element) {
                element.setAttribute('id', element.getAttribute('data-id'));
                document.getElementById("left").innerHTML += 'id="' +
                    element.getAttribute('data-id') +
                    '" start loading!<br>';
            });
        }

        var thirdBatch = function (callback) {
            var lastDivs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-last-id]'));
            countLoad = lastDivs.length;
            completionCallback = LastBatch;
            lastDivs.forEach(function (element) {
                element.setAttribute('id', element.getAttribute('data-last-id'));
                document.getElementById("left").innerHTML += 'id="' +
                    element.getAttribute('data-last-id') +
                    '" start loading!<br>';
            });
        }

        function LastBatch() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                document
                    .getElementById("right")
                    .innerHTML += '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/?' + i + '" style="width: 30px;height: 30px;" />';
            }
        }

        firstBatch();
```

```css
{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
border-style:none;
box-sizing:border-box;
}

html, body
{
width:100%;

}

#left
{
position:absolute;
width:400px;

left:0px;
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
background-color:#ffcc00;
padding:20px;
}

#right
{
position:absolute;
left:400px;
top:0px;
right:0px;
bottom:0px;
background-color:#eeeeee;
padding:20px;
}


#one { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ffcc00/cc33ff); }
#two { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ff0000/000000); }
#three { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/00cc00/33cccc); }
#four { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/330033/ff33ff); }
#five { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ffcccc/0033ff); }
#six { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/bbcc11/dddd00); }
#seven { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/0033bb/222bbb); }
#eight { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/2211bb/00bb11); }
#nine { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ffcc00/22ccff); }
#ten { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ffcc00/33ccff); }
#eleven { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/f0cc00/333333); }
#twelve { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/f1c20b/c13bf2); }
#thirteen { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/f0cd00/cf33f0); }
#fourteen { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ff0b01/0001ff); }
#fifteen { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ffbb00/dd31ff); }
#sixteen { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ffd100/cc33ff); }
#seventeen { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ffec10/000000); }
#eighteen { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/fbccfd/ff33ff); }
#nineteen { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ccccff/cf33f0); }
#twenty { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/00ccee/cc33ff); }
#twentyone { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ddccee/dddd00); }
#twentytwo { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/bbee00/cc33ff); }
#twentythree { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/11c000/c13bf2); }
#twentyfour { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/44c200/00bb11); }
#twentyfive { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/22ca00/33cccc); }
#twentysix { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/bbcf00/cc33ff); }
#twentyseven { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/ffbb00/00bb11); }
#twentyeight { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/eedd00/cc33ff); }
#twentynine { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/00ff00/33ccff); }
#thirty { background-image:url(https://placehold.it/999x999/220000/c13bf2); }

.testdiv
{
width:30px;
height:30px;
overflow:hidden;
margin:5px;

display:inline-block;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:30px;
color:#ffffff;
text-align:center;
line-height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="left"></div>

<div id="right">

    <div class="testdiv" first-id="one">1</div>
    <div class="testdiv" first-id="two">2</div>
    <div class="testdiv" first-id="three">3</div>
    <div class="testdiv" first-id="four">4</div>
    <div class="testdiv" first-id="five">5</div>
    <div class="testdiv" first-id="six">6</div>
    <div class="testdiv" first-id="seven">7</div>
    <div class="testdiv" first-id="eight">8</div>
    <div class="testdiv" first-id="nine">9</div>
    <div class="testdiv" first-id="ten">10</div>
    <div class="testdiv" first-id="eleven">11</div>
    <div class="testdiv" first-id="twelve">12</div>
    <div class="testdiv" first-id="thirteen">13</div>
    <div class="testdiv" first-id="fourteen">14</div>
    <div class="testdiv" first-id="fifteen">15</div>

    <div class="testdiv" data-id="sixteen">16</div>
    <div class="testdiv" data-id="seventeen">17</div>
    <div class="testdiv" data-id="eighteen">18</div>
    <div class="testdiv" data-id="nineteen">19</div>
    <div class="testdiv" data-id="twenty">20</div>
    <div class="testdiv" data-id="twentyone">21</div>
    <div class="testdiv" data-id="twentytwo">22</div>
    <div class="testdiv" data-id="twentythree">23</div>
    <div class="testdiv" data-id="twentyfour">24</div>
    <div class="testdiv" data-id="twentyfive">25</div>

    <div class="testdiv" data-last-id="twentysix">26</div>
    <div class="testdiv" data-last-id="twentyseven">27</div>
    <div class="testdiv" data-last-id="twentyeight">28</div>
    <div class="testdiv" data-last-id="twentynine">29</div>
    <div class="testdiv" data-last-id="thirty">30</div>

</div>
```